# upon entering/leaving the page append a string in the url. Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, url, post

Is there a way to append a string in the url upon leaving/entering?

Say the default url is `www.foo.com`

Then upon entering/leaving, it becomes `www.foo.com?param=1` without clicking to something?

Just using javascript.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: First, why "param=1"; I mean yes, that's possible - but why? Consider the "load" and "unload" events.

Comment: That might be the only way to do my task. I mean, need the parameters to do charting. Anyway, can you show me how it's done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible method to do that. This is using jQuery, and only adds the parameter on page entry (on page leave, it's kind of pointless; also, that would trigger on addition for the first case as well) -

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( window ).load(function() {
        if (! window.location.href.contains("param=0")) {
                window.location.href = window.location.href+"?param=0";
        }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest ways to do this would be to change **document.location.search** (which targets parameters) like this:

```
    if (document.location.search != ("?param=1")) {
        document.location.search = "?param=1";
    }
```

note that this essentially triggers a page reload though.